# i try to spend a variable in my partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i try to spend a variable in my partial `_showLastMeal.rb`, before to come for asking your help i read http://api.rubyonrails.org and i try to find a solution in staskoverflow

```
<%= render :partial => "calendars/showLastMeal", :locals => { :calendar => "calendar" }  -%>
```

In `calendar_controller.rb`:

```
def showLastMeal
  @lastMeal = @user.calendar.findMeal
end
```

And the model

```
 class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :event, :published_on, :description, :user_id, :description_meal
   belongs_to :user #, :foreign_key => :user_id
   scope :findMeal, lambda { order('created_at').limit(6) }
 end
```

i use rails 3.2.2

Comment: `:locals => { :calendar => "calendar" }` isn't right.  You should pass it a variable like `calendar` or `@calendar`.

Comment: `:calendar => "calendar"` sure looks suspicious.  What exactly is your question?  Does the `showLastMeal` (Ruby naming convetions would suggest `show_last_meal`, btw.) throw an error?  If so, what?

Comment: i tryed with <%= render :partial => "calendars/show_Last_Meal", :locals => { :calendar => @calendar }  -%> and i get the same error nill object in my partial i just try to <% debbug lastMeal %> theyre is manipulation to do with the model  ??? is just a question

Comment: @zyriuse: Your question does not provide enough information for us to go on. You've provided the code, but no information about what actually is breaking. Please show us the stacktrace of your error.

Comment: @zyriuse another thing, when you write a comment to someone in your own question, ensure to add before their username with an"@", like `@someone`, or they will never know that you respond them